# Extract Specific Email Address

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to extract an email address from the "From" section of the data and am drawing a blank, should Regex be used?

### Example:

```
From: RP [mailto: demo@gmail.com]
Date: Thu, Jun 23, 2016 at 2:21 PM
Subject: testing
To: RP <demo1@gmail.com>
```

The final result will return `demo@gmail.com` and not `demo1@gmail.com`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, here, it's way better if you tell us what you've try to achieve this and why it didn't work. Please, [edit] your question :)

Comment: Well, if you are using a C# programming environment, you do not need a regex, you can just get it with splitting and trimming and LINQ. If you only can use a regex for this, let us know why. Please share what you tried to help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using regex use a look behind and define what should be behind it so to only get the *From* email address

```
(?<=From:[^\[]+\[mailto:\s)(?<Email>[^\]]+)
```

Here is an example

```
var data = @"From: RP [mailto: demo@gmail.com]
Date: Thu, Jun 23, 2016 at 2:21 PM
Subject: testing
To: RP <demo1@gmail.com>";

var pattern = @"(?<=From:[^\[]+\[mailto:\s)(?<Email>[^\]]+)";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(data, pattern).Groups["Email"].Value); // demo@gmail.com
```

Comment: thanks. its working

Answer (score 1):

You can use a non-regex approach:

```
var s = @"From: RP [mailto: demo@gmail.com]
Date: Thu, Jun 23, 2016 at 2:21 PM
Subject: testing
To: RP <demo1@gmail.com>";
var res = s.Split('\n')                // Split with newlines
    .Where(l => l.StartsWith("From:")) // If a line starts with `From:`
    .Select(m => m.Split().LastOrDefault().TrimEnd(']')) // Split with spaces, get the last chunk and trim from ]
    .FirstOrDefault();   // Get the first (if there is one only one) result
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

If you need a regex by all means:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(s, @"\[mailto:\s*(.*?)]").Groups[1].Value);
```

See this [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/zHk2Ep)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `mailto:` - a literal string `mailto:`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 matching any characters up to the first
- `]` - closing `]`